# Coinslider...adding code to stop looping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the Coin Slider on my website but encountered a very unexpected surprise today when my client asked me to have the slideshow stop on the last slide. Apparently it's not built in and there's no option to have it stop.

I was hoping someone could help me find where it's looping in the script and suggest a way to add in this option.

I don't even mind having 2 versions of the script, one that loops and one that doesn't.

```
function loadContent(elementSelector, sourceURL) {
    $(""+elementSelector+"").load("http://localhost/auxtest/"+sourceURL+"");
}

(function($) {

var params      = new Array;
var order       = new Array;
var images      = new Array;
var links       = new Array;
var linksTarget = new Array;
var titles      = new Array;
var interval    = new Array;
var imagePos    = new Array;
var appInterval = new Array;    
var squarePos   = new Array;    
var reverse     = new Array;

$.fn.coinslider= $.fn.CoinSlider = function(options){

    init = function(el){

        order[el.id]        = new Array();  // order of square appereance
        images[el.id]       = new Array();
        links[el.id]        = new Array();
        linksTarget[el.id]  = new Array();
        titles[el.id]       = new Array();
        imagePos[el.id]     = 0;
        squarePos[el.id]    = 0;
        reverse[el.id]      = 1;                        

        params[el.id] = $.extend({}, $.fn.coinslider.defaults, options);

        // create images, links and titles arrays
        $.each($('#'+el.id+' img'), function(i,item){
            images[el.id][i]        = $(item).attr('src');
            links[el.id][i]         = $(item).parent().is('a') ? $(item).parent().attr('href') : '';
            linksTarget[el.id][i]   = $(item).parent().is('a') ? $(item).parent().attr('target') : '';
            titles[el.id][i]        = $(item).next().is('span') ? $(item).next().html() : '';
            $(item).hide();
            $(item).next().hide();
        });         


        // set panel
        $(el).css({
            'background-image':'url('+images[el.id][0]+')',
            'width': params[el.id].width,
            'height': params[el.id].height,
            'position': 'relative',
            'background-position': 'top left'
        }).wrap("<div class='coin-slider' id='coin-slider-"+el.id+"' />");  


        // create title bar
        $('#'+el.id).append("<div class='cs-title' id='cs-title-"+el.id+"' style='position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0; z-index: 1000;'></div>");

        $.setFields(el);

        if(params[el.id].navigation)
            $.setNavigation(el);

        $.transition(el,0);
        $.transitionCall(el);

    }

    // squares positions
    $.setFields = function(el){

        tWidth = sWidth = parseInt(params[el.id].width/params[el.id].spw);
        tHeight = sHeight = parseInt(params[el.id].height/params[el.id].sph);

        counter = sLeft = sTop = 0;
        tgapx = gapx = params[el.id].width - params[el.id].spw*sWidth;
        tgapy = gapy = params[el.id].height - params[el.id].sph*sHeight;

        for(i=1;i <= params[el.id].sph;i++){
            gapx = tgapx;

                if(gapy > 0){
                    gapy--;
                    sHeight = tHeight+1;
                } else {
                    sHeight = tHeight;
                }

            for(j=1; j <= params[el.id].spw; j++){  

                if(gapx > 0){
                    gapx--;
                    sWidth = tWidth+1;
                } else {
                    sWidth = tWidth;
                }

                order[el.id][counter] = i+''+j;
                counter++;

                if(params[el.id].links)
                    $('#'+el.id).append("<a href='"+links[el.id][0]+"' class='cs-"+el.id+"' id='cs-"+el.id+i+j+"' style='width:"+sWidth+"px; height:"+sHeight+"px; float: left; position: absolute;'></a>");
                else
                    $('#'+el.id).append("<div class='cs-"+el.id+"' id='cs-"+el.id+i+j+"' style='width:"+sWidth+"px; height:"+sHeight+"px; float: left; position: absolute;'></div>");

                // positioning squares
                $("#cs-"+el.id+i+j).css({ 
                    'background-position': -sLeft +'px '+(-sTop+'px'),
                    'left' : sLeft ,
                    'top': sTop
                });

                sLeft += sWidth;
            }

            sTop += sHeight;
            sLeft = 0;                  

        }


        $('.cs-'+el.id).mouseover(function(){
            $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).show();
        });

        $('.cs-'+el.id).mouseout(function(){
            $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).hide();
        }); 

        $('#cs-title-'+el.id).mouseover(function(){
            $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).show();
        });

        $('#cs-title-'+el.id).mouseout(function(){
            $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).hide();
        }); 

        if(params[el.id].hoverPause){   
            $('.cs-'+el.id).mouseover(function(){
                params[el.id].pause = true;
            });

            $('.cs-'+el.id).mouseout(function(){
                params[el.id].pause = false;
            }); 

            $('#cs-title-'+el.id).mouseover(function(){
                params[el.id].pause = true;
            });

            $('#cs-title-'+el.id).mouseout(function(){
                params[el.id].pause = false;
            }); 
        }


    };


    $.transitionCall = function(el){

        clearInterval(interval[el.id]); 
        delay = params[el.id].delay + params[el.id].spw*params[el.id].sph*params[el.id].sDelay;
        interval[el.id] = setInterval(function() { $.transition(el)  }, delay);

    }

    // transitions
    $.transition = function(el,direction){

        if(params[el.id].pause == true) return;

        $.effect(el);

        squarePos[el.id] = 0;
        appInterval[el.id] = setInterval(function() { $.appereance(el,order[el.id][squarePos[el.id]])  },params[el.id].sDelay);

        $(el).css({ 'background-image': 'url('+images[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]+')' });

        if(typeof(direction) == "undefined")
            imagePos[el.id]++;
        else
            if(direction == 'prev')
                imagePos[el.id]--;
            else
                imagePos[el.id] = direction;

        if  (imagePos[el.id] == images[el.id].length) {
            imagePos[el.id] = 0;
        }

        if (imagePos[el.id] == -1){
            imagePos[el.id] = images[el.id].length-1;
        }

        $('.cs-button-'+el.id).removeClass('cs-active');
        $('#cs-button-'+el.id+"-"+(imagePos[el.id]+1)).addClass('cs-active');

        if(titles[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]){
            $('#cs-title-'+el.id).css({ 'opacity' : 0 }).animate({ 'opacity' : params[el.id].opacity }, params[el.id].titleSpeed);
            $('#cs-title-'+el.id).html(titles[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]);
        } else {
            $('#cs-title-'+el.id).css('opacity',0);
        }               

    };

    $.appereance = function(el,sid){

        $('.cs-'+el.id).attr('href',links[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]).attr('target',linksTarget[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]);

        if (squarePos[el.id] == params[el.id].spw*params[el.id].sph) {
            clearInterval(appInterval[el.id]);
            return;
        }

        $('#cs-'+el.id+sid).css({ opacity: 0, 'background-image': 'url('+images[el.id][imagePos[el.id]]+')' });
        $('#cs-'+el.id+sid).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 300);
        squarePos[el.id]++;

    };

    // navigation
    $.setNavigation = function(el){
        // create prev and next 
        $(el).append("<div id='cs-navigation-"+el.id+"'></div>");
        $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).hide();

        $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).append("<a href='#' id='cs-prev-"+el.id+"' class='cs-prev'>&nbsp;</a>");
        $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).append("<a href='#' id='cs-next-"+el.id+"' class='cs-next'>&nbsp;</a>");
        $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).append("<a href='javascript:loadContent('#world', 'auxworld.php');' id='cs-back-"+el.id+"' class='cs-back'>&nbsp;</a>");
        $('#cs-prev-'+el.id).css({
            'position'  : 'absolute',
            'top'       : params[el.id].height/2 - 15,
            'left'      : 0,
            'z-index'   : 1001,
            'line-height': '30px',
            'opacity'   : params[el.id].opacity
        }).click( function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.transition(el,'prev');
            $.transitionCall(el);       
        }).mouseover( function(){ $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).show() });

        $('#cs-next-'+el.id).css({
            'position'  : 'absolute',
            'top'       : params[el.id].height/2 - 15,
            'right'     : 0,
            'z-index'   : 1005,
            'line-height': '30px',
            'opacity'   : params[el.id].opacity
        }).click( function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.transition(el);
            $.transitionCall(el);
        }).mouseover( function(){ $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).show() });

        $('#cs-back-'+el.id).css({
            'position'  : 'absolute',
            'top'       : params[el.id].height/2 - 15,
            'right'     : 0,
            'z-index'   : 1001,
            'line-height': '30px',
            'opacity'   : params[el.id].opacity
        }).click( function(){
             window.location.replace('index.php');
            // loadContent('#world', 'auxworld.php'); 
        }).mouseover( function(){ $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).show() });



        // image buttons
        $("<div id='cs-buttons-"+el.id+"' class='cs-buttons'></div>").appendTo($('#coin-slider-'+el.id));


        for(k=1;k<images[el.id].length+1;k++){
            $('#cs-buttons-'+el.id).append("<a href='#' class='cs-button-"+el.id+"' id='cs-button-"+el.id+"-"+k+"'>"+k+"</a>");
        }

        $.each($('.cs-button-'+el.id), function(i,item){
            $(item).click( function(e){
                $('.cs-button-'+el.id).removeClass('cs-active');
                $(this).addClass('cs-active');
                e.preventDefault();
                $.transition(el,i);
                $.transitionCall(el);               
            })
        }); 

        $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id+' a').mouseout(function(){
            $('#cs-navigation-'+el.id).hide();
            params[el.id].pause = false;
        });                     

        $("#cs-buttons-"+el.id).css({
            'left'          : '50%',
            'margin-left'   : -images[el.id].length*15/2-5,
            'position'      : 'relative'

        });


    }




    // effects
    $.effect = function(el){

        effA = ['random','swirl','rain','straight'];
        if(params[el.id].effect == '')
            eff = effA[Math.floor(Math.random()*(effA.length))];
        else
            eff = params[el.id].effect;

        order[el.id] = new Array();

        if(eff == 'random'){
            counter = 0;
              for(i=1;i <= params[el.id].sph;i++){
                for(j=1; j <= params[el.id].spw; j++){  
                    order[el.id][counter] = i+''+j;
                    counter++;
                }
              } 
            $.random(order[el.id]);
        }

        if(eff == 'rain')   {
            $.rain(el);
        }

        if(eff == 'swirl')
            $.swirl(el);

        if(eff == 'straight')
            $.straight(el);

        reverse[el.id] *= -1;
        if(reverse[el.id] > 0){
            order[el.id].reverse();
        }

    }


    // shuffle array function
    $.random = function(arr) {

      var i = arr.length;
      if ( i == 0 ) return false;
      while ( --i ) {
         var j = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( i + 1 ) );
         var tempi = arr[i];
         var tempj = arr[j];
         arr[i] = tempj;
         arr[j] = tempi;
       }
    }   

    //swirl effect by milos popovic
    $.swirl = function(el){

        var n = params[el.id].sph;
        var m = params[el.id].spw;

        var x = 1;
        var y = 1;
        var going = 0;
        var num = 0;
        var c = 0;

        var dowhile = true;

        while(dowhile) {

            num = (going==0 || going==2) ? m : n;

            for (i=1;i<=num;i++){

                order[el.id][c] = x+''+y;
                c++;

                if(i!=num){
                    switch(going){
                        case 0 : y++; break;
                        case 1 : x++; break;
                        case 2 : y--; break;
                        case 3 : x--; break;

                    }
                }
            }

            going = (going+1)%4;

            switch(going){
                case 0 : m--; y++; break;
                case 1 : n--; x++; break;
                case 2 : m--; y--; break;
                case 3 : n--; x--; break;       
            }

            check = $.max(n,m) - $.min(n,m);            
            if(m<=check && n<=check)
                dowhile = false;

        }
    }

    // rain effect
    $.rain = function(el){
        var n = params[el.id].sph;
        var m = params[el.id].spw;

        var c = 0;
        var to = to2 = from = 1;
        var dowhile = true;


        while(dowhile){

            for(i=from;i<=to;i++){
                order[el.id][c] = i+''+parseInt(to2-i+1);
                c++;
            }

            to2++;

            if(to < n && to2 < m && n<m){
                to++;   
            }

            if(to < n && n>=m){
                to++;   
            }

            if(to2 > m){
                from++;
            }

            if(from > to) dowhile= false;

        }           

    }

    // straight effect
    $.straight = function(el){
        counter = 0;
        for(i=1;i <= params[el.id].sph;i++){
            for(j=1; j <= params[el.id].spw; j++){  
                order[el.id][counter] = i+''+j;
                counter++;
            }

        }
    }

    $.min = function(n,m){
        if (n>m) return m;
        else return n;
    }

    $.max = function(n,m){
        if (n<m) return m;
        else return n;
    }       

this.each (
    function(){ init(this); }
);


};


// default values
$.fn.coinslider.defaults = {       
     width: 1230, // width of slider panel  
     height: 500, // height of slider panel  
     spw: 20, // squares per width  
     sph: 1, // squares per height  
     delay: 7000, // delay between images in ms  
     sDelay: .1, // delay beetwen squares in ms  
     opacity: 0.9, // opacity of title and navigation  
     titleSpeed: 1160, // speed of title appereance in ms  
     effect: 'rain', // random, swirl, rain, straight  
     navigation: true, // prev next and buttons  
     links : false, // show images as links   
     hoverPause: true // pause on hover            
};

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Do you want it to stop at last slide and that's it - without the option to resume? Also - what is suppose to happend when user clicks on last mini-square (that *navigation* or whatever) should it stop cycling at that point, or run just one more time and then stop after reaching last slide ?

Comment: ↺ Please consider the environment before printing this question. :)

Comment: @wtk It should stop at the last slide and that's it.  The navigation doesn't need to change to at all since we still want users to be able to go back and forth between slides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the code of coin slider with extra option `stopAtLastSlide`, that can be passed to coinslider function stop the automatic rotation when it reaches last image.

Check working example here http://jsfiddle.net/wtk_pl/Lrsj2/7/. Source code for updated coin slider can be found here https://github.com/WTK/Coin-Slider.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to modify the `$.transitionCall` function. This set's the new timeout for displaying the next element.

Maybe you can find out here if it wants to render the last element and then skip setting the interval

```
$.transitionCall = function(el) {

    clearInterval(interval[el.id]);
    delay = params[el.id].delay + params[el.id].spw * params[el.id].sph * params[el.id].sDelay;
    interval[el.id] = setInterval(function() {
        $.transition(el)
    }, delay);

}
```

Another option for not stopping the interval is setting `params[el.id].pause = true;`